# Writing to Spark Avro failing

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mapr

We have a MapR Cluster, on which this was running but now suddenly its stopped and even does not work on mapr demo cluster. We are running MapR 5.1 and Spark 1.6.1.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('test')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(2012, 8, "Batman", 9.8), (2012, 8, "Hero", 8.7), (2012, 7, "Robot", 5.5), (2011, 7, "Git", 2.0)],["year", "month", "title", "rating"])
df.show()
  df.write.mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("/user/bedrock/output_avro")
sc.stop()
```

But now i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldDefault from class    com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters$$anonfun$convertStructToAvro$1
```

Any ideas? This is as per the instructions on databricks github. I am invoking the pyspark shell or spark-submit using these packages:

```
/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/bin/pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1 --driver-class-path /opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.6.1/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar --master yarn-client
```

Comment: @zero323, do you have input on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this error in the past, but not with pyspark.  I'm hoping that my experience can help.

It turned out that there was a badly configured Java CLASSPATH that placed `avro-1.7.5.jar` before any others.  You might be able to solve this by ensuring that your cluster configuration uses `avro-1.7.7.jar`.

You can usually do this by setting the `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` and `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` configuration variables to `true`.

The specific error is triggered by a change to Avro between 1.7.5 and 1.7.6 (see https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/release-1.7.5/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.java#L2136)